# How can I specialize a template that is already specialized

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Suppose I have this template:

```
template<class T, int a, int b>
class Foo
```

I have a partial specialized version of the above template for char:

```
template<int a, int b>
class Foo<char, a, b>
```

How can I further specialize the above template for, say, a = 1?

Comment: `template<int b> class Foo<char, 1, b>`?

Comment: how can the compiler know if it's specialized from the first or the second?

Comment: You can't specialize a specialization, you can only make another specialization be a better match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specialize a specialization, you can only make another specialization be a better match.